# Zero phase filtering of FIR from filter and Analysis Toolbox

Tags: matlab, filter

How can i use filtfilt  function  in the following filter created by matlab filter analysis toolbox.My matlab is 2012.
Below is the syntax but i don't know the variables inside the parentheses y = filtfilt(b,a,x)   y = filtfilt(sos,g,x) y = filtfilt(d,x)

```
% MATLAB Code
% Generated by MATLAB(R) 8.2 and the Signal Processing Toolbox 6.20.
% Generated on: 18-Mar-2019 12:11:31
% Equiripple Lowpass filter designed using the FIRPM function.
% All frequency values are in Hz.
data = xlsread('Smoothendata2.xlsx',1);% read csv content
d1 = data(:,1);                                                    % Original Time Vector
d2 = data(:,2);                                                    % Original Data Vector
L = length(d1);
tv = linspace(min(d1), max(d1), L);                             % Time Vector For Interpolation
dv = interp1(d1, d2, tv, 'linear');                             % Interpolated Data Vector
Ts = mean(diff(tv));                                            % Sampling Time Interval
t_stats = [Ts  std(tv)];
Fs = 1/Ts;                                                      % Sampling Frequency
Fn = Fs/2;                                                      % Nyquist Frequency
FTD = fft(dv)/L;                                                % Fourier Transform
Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn;                             % Frequency Vector
Iv = 1:length(Fv);                                              % Index Vector
figure(1)
semilogy(Fv, abs(FTD(Iv))*2)                                    % Plot Fourier Transform
grid
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
% 
Fpass = 50;             % Passband Frequency
Fstop = 60;             % Stopband Frequency
Dpass = 0.17099735734;  % Passband Ripple
Dstop = 1;              % Stopband Attenuation
dens  = 20;             % Density Factor
% Calculate the order from the parameters using FIRPMORD.
[N, Fo, Ao, W] = firpmord([Fpass, Fstop]/(Fs/2), [1 0], [Dpass, Dstop]);
% Calculate the coefficients using the FIRPM function.
b  = firpm(N, Fo, Ao, W, {dens});
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `filtfilt` command is not only made to apply FIR but also IIR filters.
As the FIR has no feedback, in contrast to the IIR filter, it only depends on the feedforward filter coefficients which are defined by `b`. (the feedback coefficients are represented by `a`)

As you are interested in applying it for a FIR filter you can set `a=1`;

So the answer to your question is:

```
b  = firpm(N, Fo, Ao, W, {dens});
a=1;    
y = filtfilt(b,a,x)
```